# get/set Accessors the correct scope

Tags: c#

i created a class called ProfileHelper, and I can't seem to get my get/set accessors correct; instead, I'm getting red lines on both get and set.  Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
public static String UserName(string columnName)
{ 
    get
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(SiteConfig.ConnectionString))
        {
            string sSql = ("SELECT UserName , LoweredUserName FROM  aspnet_Users  WHERE UserId = @UserId");

            using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(sSql, cn))
            {
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString());
                cn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader rd = cm.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rd.Read())
                    {
                        return columnName;
                    }
                    rd.Close();
                }
                cn.Close();
            }         
        }            
        return columnName;
    }
    set
    {
        using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(SiteConfig.ConnectionString))
        {
            string sSql = ("UPDATE [aspnet_ Users] SET UserName = @UserName, LoweredUserName = @LoweredUserName WHERE UserId = @UserId");

            using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(sSql, cn))
            {
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Membership.GetUser ().ProviderUserKey.ToString());
                cn.Open();
                cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cn.Close();
            }    
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post instead of putting code in your comments. Also provide more information. What error do you get, what have you tried.

Comment: Properties shouldn't be accessing the database. They are supposed to be simple - doing very little work.

Comment: You really shouldn't be doing so much work in your getters and setters.

Comment: your code is function/property hybrid :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Syntax is basically:

```
private string userName;
public string UserName // no parameter here!
{
  get { return this.userName; }
  set { this.userName = value; } // value is a keyword
}
```

Alternatively, auto-property do the backing field for you:

```
public string UserName { get; set; } // equivalent
public string MyExternallyReadOnly { get; private set; } // setter is private
```

You should *not* fiddle around with SQL connections in properties. Access to properties should be fast and reliable. Consider replacing it by methods to make it clear that this is actually a longer-enduring action with external dependencies (which is more likely to fail):

```
public string GetUserName() { }
public void UpdateUserName() {}
```

Comment: Wherever you'd use the `UserName` property. I edited my answer, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: yes it is quite clear,on the other hand i need to call the method in my profile page using the helper class where i created a method called Public Static String username(string ColumnName){} using the select and update query ..What i dont understand is how am i Suppose to use the get/set and where?

Comment: In general properties are used to exposed the internal state (instance field values) of an object most of the type, where access is actually fast and reliable. To be honest I don't fully understand what your code is supposed to do, so I'm struggling to suggest you very specific things to do...

Answer (score 8):

That's a method, not a property.  Only properties have get and set accessors.  Pick one.

```
public static String UserName(string columnName) // this implies a method
     { 
      get // this implies a property
      {
```

Comment: Of course, if he wants separate getter and setter code, and if he still wants a parameter `columnName`, he could write an indexer. An indexer is like a property, but it can take one or more parameters. (Of course the setter has an additional "invisible" parameter `value`.) Not that I'm recommending using an indexer in this case, but it sure is one kind hybrid between a method and a property.

Answer (score 2):

You should make a pair of methods, `GetUserName(string columnName)` and `SetUserName(string columnName, string value)`.  This is the preferred approach when it will probably take a while, e.g. because you're making a DB connection, and lets you easily have a parameter.

`public static String UserName(string columnName)` is the signature for a method.  `public static String UserName` would be a property.  Properties have get/set accessors, methods do not.  You need to change this.  Properties do not allow arguments, except for [indexed properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), which can't be static (e.g. used like `myObj[someColumnName]`, declared like `public string this[string columnName]`).  If you're expecting to access the property like `var something = ProfileHelper.UserName;`, just use a property.